# How to avoid automatic subscription of observables after combineLatest?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Let's say I got 2 observables.

```
obsA => this.usersList$
obsB => a function that returns an observable
```

I'm using the combine like this:

```
   return combineLatest([this.getIdFromUser$(id), this.usersList$]).pipe(
      map(([user, userList]) => {
          ... here I call another function that will at the end, add a new user to the 
              observable list.
      })
   );
```

This combineLatest is being triggered after a **click subject**. When usersList$ observable is updated, the whole chain gets called again, even if I didn't click again, just because one observable of the chain changed.

How can I prevent this from happening? I don't want to unsuscribe to the whole thing, as you can actually keep clicking a button to change the state of the button (toggle it).

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the whole usecase. If you don't want to listen to changes of the usersList$, perhaps you're better off using [withLatestFrom](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/withLatestFrom)?

Comment: Interesting, would this withLatestForm be used before the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment under your question, you could go with:

```
return this.getIdFromUser$(id)
    .pipe(
        withLatestFrom(this.usersList$),
        map(([user, userList]) => {
          ... here I call another function that will at the end, add a new user to the observable list.
      })
    );
```

This will emit every time `this.getIdFromUser$(id)` emits (which I assume happens on the mentioned click event), but only after `this.usersList$` has emitted at least once. It will always contain latest value of `this.usersList$`.

Comment: It works. Now I realize what was going on with this code. As this function was also being used on a different place to check the status of the user, hence... the multiple calls being triggered.